Metabolism of Purple non-Sulfur bacteria
I am a high school student who is currently experimenting with hydrogen sulfide absorption using bacteria. I know species of purple sulfur bacteria or green sulfur bacteria are able to oxidize hydrogen sulfide but the only species that is available to me is Rhodospirillum rubrum which is a purple non-sulfur bacteria.
I know under anaerobic conditions, r. rubrum receives energy by oxidizing hydrogen with carbon monoxide or uses sulfide as an electron donor in photosynthesis(source).
Is it possible for r. rubrum to use hydrogen sulfide as an electron donor similar to purple sulfur bacteria? They both use the photosynthetic pigments Bacteriochlorophylls so does this mean both r. rubrum and PSB can use hydrogen sulfide as an electron donor and thus oxidize it?
